# Move nodes to the end of Linked List function Problem

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm a student in C programming and I'm just learning the basics for now. I need to write a function that given a linked list in input, put the nodes containing a multiple of 5 and 3 to the end of the list. I'm trying with a sort of recursive approach, but the program crashes.
The exercise guidelines say I cannot delete nodes and then recreate them at the end of the list. I must modify pointers.

EDIT: The debugger says it's a segmentation fault problem.

Here there is the image of the debug errors with this list (15 -> 7 -> 2 -> 1 -> 30 -> 25 -> 10) given in input:
[segfaultdebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZANHh.png)

```
//node is a type I defined for linked list nodes

node *multipleOf3And5ToTail(node *head){

    node *temp2=head;

    if((head->val%3==0)&&(head->val%5==0)&&head!=NULL){

         while(temp2->next!=NULL){
            temp2=temp2->next;
          }

          temp2->next=head;
          head=head->next;
          temp2->next->next=NULL;
          head->next=mul5e3coda(head->next);
    }
    else{
         while(((head->val%3!=0)||(head->val%5!=0))&&head!=NULL){
            head=head->next;}
         if((head->val%3==0)&&(head->val%5==0)&&head!=NULL){
            head=mul5e3coda(head);
         }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] around this which conveniently provides a filled list to play with and demonstrates the error you observe?

Comment: Don't try to do to much at the same time. I suggest you create a single function to remove a selected node from the list. And a second function to add a node to the end of the list. Then you use these functions instead.

Comment: Also, now is a very good time to learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes, and how to locate where in your code they happen and how to check the values of involved variables at the location of the crash.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I cannot add or remove nodes, I must modify pointers. I use CodeBlocks as IDE... How to use the debugger?                                                   15 -> 7 -> 2 -> 1 -> 30 -> 25 -> 10 is an example. the output should be             7 -> 2 -> 1 -> 25 -> 10 -> 15 -> 30

Comment: @pochopsp Moving a node entalis removing it from a list and then adding it (the same node) to a different place in the list. There is no way around it. The guidelines say, as far as I can tell, that you cannot *delete and recreate* a node, which is quite different from *remove and add*. To illustrate, moving a book to a different place on a bookshelf normally entails removing and adding. To delete and recreate, you would have to shred the book and then print a new copy. This is what your exercise doesn't want you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! I solved my own problem writing a different code.

```c
bool isMultipleOf3And5(int n){
    return n%3==0 && n%5==0;
}

node* getTail(node *head){
    while(head->next != NULL)
        head = head->next;
    return head;
}

node* multipleOf3And5ToTail(node *head){

    node *prev=NULL, *curr=head, *succ=NULL, *tail=NULL, *firstMultipleInTail=NULL;
    
    while(curr != NULL){
        
        while(!isMultipleOf3And5(curr->val) && curr->next != NULL){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            succ = curr->next;
        }
        if(curr == firstMultipleInTail || curr->next == NULL)
            break; // if so, we can stop
        
        if(tail == NULL) {
            // needed to check when we arrive again to it
            firstMultipleInTail = curr;
            tail = getTail(curr);
        }
        
        // put the multiple of 3 and 5 in tail
        tail->next = curr;

        // to adjust pointers:
        // if the multiple was in head, we advance head
        if(prev == NULL) head = head->next;
        // else we link the prev to the succ
        else prev->next = succ;

        // advance curr
        curr = curr->next;
        // set the end of list to NULL
        tail->next->next = NULL;
        // update the tail
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```